# cakephp containable condition problem

Tags: mysql, cakephp

assume the following tables:

- businesses_locations (location_state_id)
- users_locations(location_state_id)
- businesses_reviews(user_id, business_id).

How should a 'find' call on BusinessesReview look like in order to select only those entries where the user state DIFFERS from the business state?

```
$this->BusinessesReview->contain(array('BusinessesProfile'=>array('BusinessesLocation'),'User'=>array('UsersLocation')));
$results = $this->BusinessesReview->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('BusinessesLocation.location_state_id <> UsersLocation.location_state_id')));
```

gives error:

```
MySQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'BusinessesLocation.location_state_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put this in your `contain` call

```
$this->BusinessesReview->contain(
    array(
        'BusinessesProfile' => array(
            'BusinessesLocation' => array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'BusinessesLocation.location_state_id <> UsersLocation.location_state_id'
                )
            )
         ),
         ...  // rest of the array goes here
     )
  );
```

*Answer to comment:* Try putting the `User` array before the `BusinessesProfile` array in your `contain()`.  This is a shot in the dark but I'm guessing this might set up your `UsersLocation` to be queried first, giving you the necessary information for the `BusinessesProfile` query.

Comment: It seemed to move a step closer, now i'm getting: Unknown column 'UsersLocation.location_state_id' in 'where clause'.. any idea? :)